# How do I test this with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec

I'm using the Sorcery gem for user signup/login.

One feature of this gem is the `require_login` before_filter on any controller you want to authenticate.

I have created a `dashboard` namespace for my app after they've logged in. For example `/dashboard/reports` or `/dashboard/employees`, etc.

Routes file:

```
# Dashboard                                                
namespace :dashboard do                                      
  # Recent Activity                                          
  get '' => redirect('/dashboard/recent-activity')           
  get 'recent-activity' => 'activities#index', :as => 'root' 
  # Other dashboard controllers and actions
end
```

I extracted out the before_filter into it's own controller called:

"app/controllers/dashboard/base_controller.rb"

```
class Dashboard::BaseController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :require_login

end
```

What I'd like to do is make 100% sure in some kind of test that ANY new controller I create within the dashboard folder (or dashboard namespace), inherits from `Dashboard::BaseController`

Such as my activities controller for example:

`class Dashboard::ActivitiesController < Dashboard::BaseController`

I dont want to go creating controllers in a few months and accidentally make it inherit from ApplicationController which would still would but wouldnt have login functionality.

I'm using RSpec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't quite believe my own eyes that I solved this on my own....

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Dashboard::BaseController do

  it "is the superclass of every dashboard namespaced controller" do
    Rails.application.eager_load!
    ApplicationController.descendants.each do |controller|
      if controller.to_s.include?("Dashboard::") && controller.to_s != "Dashboard::BaseController"
        expect(controller.superclass.to_s).to eq("Dashboard::BaseController")      
      end
    end
  end

end
```